# crontab -> shellscript -> docker -> redirect output to localfile

Tags: docker, bash, cron

I am currently switching from rsync to a borg based backup.

Everything is working, except getting the output of borg to my logfile.

My setup is as follows:

- I am trying to do everything in docker to have my server as slim as possible and being able to recreate quickly. So I am running borg via a docker container.
- a central local_backup.sh that issues several backup tasks, including the borg task
- Inside the script, I am executing borg backup via "docker run.." (excerpt):

```
echo "--- nextcloud backup"
docker run --rm \
    -e BORG_UNKNOWN_UNENCRYPTED_REPO_ACCESS_IS_OK=yes \
    -v /root/.cache:/root/.cache \
    -v /mnt/G/Backup/automatic/borg:/backup \
    -v /mnt/E/dockervolumes/freundx-nextcloud/nextcloud:/nextcloud:ro \
    peez/playground \
    borg create --stats --verbose --compression lz4 --exclude '*.log*' /backup::nextcloud-{now} /nextcloud

echo "--- nextcloud done"
```

- This script is called via crontab:

```
50 8    * * *   root    /opt/freundx/admin_scripts/local_backup.sh 2>&1 >> /mnt/E/logs/local_backup.log
```

The backup itself is working perfectly.
The only thing is in the logfile, I just get the two "echoes", not the outputs of borg to my local_backup.log file. Do you have an idea what I'm missing?

it's btw. not working as well when I execute the same command from the crontab file via command line. The output is done to the console, not to the file.